# File disappeared after error during move

Tags: windows, filesystems, network-shares, file-recovery

I was cut and pasting a file from one network share to another on windows. During the move an error occured and now the file isn't in the source or destination locations.

Is there any way to recover the file? I would have thought this to be a transactional process.

Comment: I just saw this disappearing act happen when moving a few files from internal SSD to USB flash drive on Windows 7.  I hooked the internal SSD to another PC and ran Recuva.  No breadcrumbs.  Shocked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recover file using

[Easy Recovery Pro](http://www.ontrackdatarecovery.co.uk/file-recovery-software/)

or

[Stellar Phoenix](http://www.stellarinfo.com/)

Check this software  : http://recover-lost-files.com/ ( it might be helpful for you )

*Note : These softwares also wont help once start writing from source*

Comment: Easy Recovery Pro will **not** recover files deleted on a network share. And Stellar Phoenix requires you to send in your hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately network share deletes are not diverted to the recycle bin.

you could check [**Undelete Plus**](http://undeleteplus.com/) on the server from where you started the copy.
Any tool that can do the following will work -- but, only while the data is really around in the deleted area.

> Accidentally deleting a file from your computer, flash disk, camera, or the like does not mean it is lost forever. Software doesn’t destroy files when it deletes, it simply marks the space the file was using as being available for re-use. If nothing has needed that space since the deletion, the data is still there and the file can be recovered.
>
> UndeletePlus is powerful software that can quickly scan a computer or storage medium for deleted files and restore them on command. It works with computers, flash drives, cameras, and other forms of data storage. Simply scan the device, select the files you want to recover, and click a button to restore the information or picture you thought was lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) for recovering files and it works like a charm! Haven't tried it on networks yet but u could run this app on the computer that you were copying the data from.. best of all this app is free

Comment: This won't work on a network share.

Comment: so who was talking about networks anyway.. read what i posted it above i wrote that he had to run it on the computer that he was copying it from.. read before u comment buddy it saves everyone's time

Comment: I read it alright. And please don't call me your buddy. The OP didn't indicate that he is the admin of the network server. And if he was, I'm sure he wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: This place is about offering help and solutions. i made it clear that i had not used it on networks.. no use you trying to reiterate a point that was made clear in the first answer itself, it's not like i was misleading the person who asked the question.. i was merely offering another option .. and in computer problems never assume things.. like whether he is admin or not depends on his position.. if it isn't clear all solutions must be offered.. but as i can see all you have done in this thread is tell people how the solutions offered dont work, didn't see u offer a solution

Comment: A solution that doesn't work or isn't applicable in the given situation can hardly be called a solution. Sometimes life just sucks and there is no solution. Sometimes my knowledge just sucks and I can not offer a solution. Tough luck.